# How to generate natural products in order?

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization

You want to have a list of the ordered products `n x m` so that both `n` and `m` are natural numbers and `1 < (n x m) < upper_limit`, say `uper_limit = 100`. Also both n and m cannot be bigger than the square root of the upper limit (therefore `n <= 10` and `m <= 10`).
The most straightforward thing to do would be to generate all the products with a list comprehension and then sort the result.

```
sorted(n*m for n in range(1,10) for m in range(1,n))
```

However when `upper_limit` becomes very big then this is not very efficient, especially if the objective is to found only one number given certain criteria (ex. find the max product such that ... -> I would want to generate the products in descending order, test them and stop the whole process as soon as I find the first one that respects the criteria).

So, how to generate this products in order?

The first thing I have done was to start from the upper_limit and go backwards one by one, making a double test:
 - checking if the number can be a product of n and m
 - checking for the criteria
Again, this is not very efficient ...
Any algorithm that solves this problem?

Comment: Please clarify the output required.  If `m` and `n` are limited to `<= sqrt(upper_limit)`, then the requirement `nm < upper_limit` is redundant.  Also, limiting the factors changes the output.  For instance, for `upper_limit=16`, should `14` be in the output?  It's a product less than 16, but it requires a factor greater than `4`.

Comment: Also, please clarify the actual problem you're solving:  (1) all composite numbers < limit; (2) all products of two factors <= root; (3) The largest number from one of those two sets.  The approach differs for each of these.

Comment: Oh, yes, that was redundant. I am trying to get the bigger composite number < limit so that both factors are <= root and a third condition can be plugged in.
The third condition is not relevant if a generator of products in descending order respecting point (1) and point (2) exists

Comment: In other words, you're trying to generate a list of products, sorted, for an unspecified usage?  Your list limited by 16 would be `[16, 12, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, and would not include `[14, 10]`.  You need the entire list, because the purpose is unspecified.  Is this correct?

Comment: The code that you give would generate e.g. 10 twice, once as 2*5 and once as 5*2. Is that desired?

Comment: Yes, correct. Whether there are repetitions or not it does not make a difference

Comment: This is a tricky problem. My formulation of it: given a product `a*b` of positive integers `<= n`, find the largest product `c*d` of positive integers subject to the constraints that `c, d <= n` and `c*d < a*b`. For `n` large enough, this boils down to finding the next smallest composite number. To get a feel for the difficulty, if `n = 50` and `a*b = 5*19 = 95`, then the next smallest product is `94 = 2*47`. Thus the next smallest number is not given by small perturbations of `a` and `b`. My guess is that you can't do much better than you are currently doing. Maybe try on [mathematics.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a slightly more efficient solution to this problem.
For a and b being natural numbers:

```
S = a + b
D = abs(a - b)
```

If S is constant, the smaller D is, the bigger a*b is.
For each S (taken in decreasing order) it is therefore possible to iterate through all the possible tuples (a, b) with increasing D.

First I plug the external condition and if the product a*b respects the condition I then iterate through other (a,b) tuples with smaller decreasing S and smaller increasing D to check if I find other numbers that respect the same condition but have a bigger a*b. I repeat the iteration until I find a number with D == 0 or 1 (because in that case there cannot be tuples with smaller S that have a higher product)

Answer (score -2):

The following code will check all the possible combinations without repetition and will stop when the condition is met. In this code if the break  is executed in the inner loop, the break statement in the outer loop is executed as well, otherwise continue statement is executed.

```
from math import sqrt
n = m = round(sqrt(int(input("Enter upper limit"))))
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i - 1, 0, -1):
        if * required condition:
            n = i
            m = j
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the question posted.

Comment: please write some explanation along with the code. code only answers are generally discouraged in SO --Review

Comment: This is not a solution, because you are not generating the products in descending order. Say upper_limit = 16, your code will generate: 12 (and not 16), 8, 4, 6, 3, 2, 0. Even if j starts from i: 16, 12, 8, 4, 9, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1